# How do I have my getter return data from attribute/metadata?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

So if I have an object with a property like so:

```
[MyCustomAttribute("somevalue")]
public string PropertyName { get; set; }
```

is it possible to have my getter return a string from a property inside the attribute? In this particular case, `MyCustomAttribute` derives from `DisplayNameProperty` and I'm trying to return `DisplayName`

how would I do this??

Comment: You said `MyCustomAttribute` derives from `DisplayNameProperty` which is confusing.  Doesn't `MyCustomAttribute` need to derive from `ValidationAttribute`???

Comment: @David Tansey, no it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that you mean that for some reason you either want to return the DisplayNameAttribute from the getter or use it for something in the setter.

Then this should do it

```
MemberInfo property = typeof(YourClass).GetProperty("PropertyName");   
var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true)
      .Cast<MyCustomAttribute>.Single();
string displayName = attribute.DisplayName;
```

Your questions isn't phrased clearly enough to give a better answer. As people say above - setters don't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to put my actual implementation in here so it hopefully helps someone. Lemme know if you see a deficiency or area for improvement.

```
// Custom attribute might be something like this
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BrandedAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly ResourceManager _rm;
    private readonly string _key;

    public BrandedAttribute(string resourceKey)
    {
        _rm = new ResourceManager("brand", typeof(BrandedAttribute).Assembly);
        _key = resourceKey;
    }

    public override string BrandText
    {
        get
        {
            // do what you need to do in order to generate the right text
            return brandA_resource.ResourceManager.GetString(_key);     
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DisplayName;
    }
}

// extension
public static string AttributeToString<T>(this object obj, string propertyName)
    where T: Attribute
{
    MemberInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

    var attribute = default(T);
    if (property != null)
    {
        attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true)
                            .Cast<T>().Single();
    }
    // I chose to do this via ToString() just for simplicity sake
    return attribute == null ? string.Empty : attribute.ToString();
}

// usage
public MyClass
{
    [MyCustom]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.AttributeToString<MyCustomAttribute>("MyProperty");
        }
    }
}
```